# Hadoop Benchmark: TestDFSIO

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am testing my hadoop configuration with the apache provided benchmark file TestDFSIO. I'm running it according to this tutorial (resource 1):

http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/#testdfsio

The usage of the test is as follows:

```
TestDFSIO.0.0.4
Usage: hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-*test*.jar TestDFSIO 
           -read | -write | -clean 
           [-nrFiles N] [-fileSize MB]
           [-resFile resultFileName] [-bufferSize Bytes]
```

I'm a little confused about some of the flags, specifically, **what is the buffer size flag for?** Also, while navigating hdfs when the job completed successfully (I first performed a write TestDFSIO), I couldn't find the filename I supposedly created by choosing a resultFileName. **Why can't I find the file by the resultFileName I used?**

I had also looked at this page (resource 2) (specifically **page 25**):

http://wr.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/_media/research/labs/2009/2009-12-tien_duc_dinh-evaluierung_von_hadoop-report.pdf

As one of the parameters of their test, they were using block sizes of 64MB and 128MB. I tried putting '64MB' (converted to bytes) after the bufferSize flag, but this led to a failed job, which leads me to believe I do not understand what the buffersize flag is for, and how to use different block sizes for testing. **How do you change the block size of the test (as per resource 2)?**

Answer (score 2):

**What is the buffer size flag for?**

The buffer size flag describes the length of the write buffer in bytes. See the WriteMapper constructor in [TestDFSIO.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/trunk/src/test/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TestDFSIO.java):

```
public WriteMapper() {
  for(int i=0; i < bufferSize; i++)
    buffer[i] = (byte)('0' + i % 50);
}
```

Here, data is generated and written to the buffer in memory before being written to disk. When it's written to disk later, it's all written in one step rather than one step per byte. Fewer writes often means better performance, so a larger buffer might improve performance.

**Why can't I find the file by the resultFileName I used?**

Results are usually automatically written to /benchmarks/TestDFSIO. If you don't find it there, search for mapred.output.dir in your job log.

**How do you change the block size of the test (as per resource 2)?**

Block size can be passed as a parameter as a [generic option](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options). Try something like:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-*test*.jar TestDFSIO -D dfs.block.size=134217728 -write
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why can't I find the file by the resultFileName I used?**
You should have probably seen a line like this at the end of job execution log:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /benchmarks/TestDFSIO/io_write/part-00000
```

while dealing with TestDFSIO it usually means that lzo or other compression is used (so there's extra something appended to the filename).

so instad of looking for

```
/benchmarking/TestDFSIO/io_write/part-00000
```

try this (see * wildcard at the end):

```
hadoop fs -ls /benchmarking/TestDFSIO/io_write/part-00000*
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this for this question (How do you change the block size of the test (as per resource 2)?**

`hadoop jar $_HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-*test*.jar.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 4 -fileSize 250GB -resFile /tmp/TestDFSIOwrite.txt`